# Cuckoo version 2.0.3 installation: agent.py not installing on virtualbox guest windows7

Tags: python, cuckoo

I'm completely new in malware research analysis field. I am trying to install cuckoo sandbox 2.0.3. It looks like it has been installed, because when I run the command $cuckoo it shows:

[image: run cuckoo]

I have windows 7 as guest in the VirtualBox and I have copied the agent.py file in the guest. According to the Cuckoo documentation, the agent.py file should show this when double clicked:

```
Starting agent on 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But in my case, whenever I double click the agent.py file, it shows black screen like this:

[image: screen]

So, I have completely stuck here and cannot proceed further. I checked the .conf files; everything looks fine, IP addresses are also given properly. So, I don't know what the actual reason for this situation is. As I have said I am completely new in this field, so any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any other information regarding my installation process.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run CMD as administrator, and the goes to the path where agent.py is installed and then type

```
Python agent.py
```

Once the agent is run try to submit.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to submit the url or file using below command on cuckoo server

Step 1: start cuckoo server

```
cuckoo -d
```

Step 2: submit url to analyzer.

```
cuckoo -d submit -u www.google.com
```

Past the logs from Cuckoo server.